# How to print all the highest value places

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot figure out how to get python to print all the highest values as it only prints the first one it encounters.

It takes standard input from a file that has on a few lines the following:
89 Michael Dunne (grade name)

I know I can use the zip function but I cannot figure out how only print the name from it

If I add "`highstudents = sorted(zip(grade,name),reverse=True)`" it sorts from high to low but I do not know how to filter the name out as it prints as "(89, 'Pepe')"

The code below is the following attempt so far.

```
import sys

def topgrade(x):
    s = max(x)
    return s


def main():
    s = sys.argv[1]
    grade=[]
    name = []
    try:    
        with open(s,'r') as studata:
            for line in studata:
                try:
                    line = line.strip()
                    grade.append(int(line[0:2]))
                    name.append(line[3::])

                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid mark",line[0:2],"encountered. Skipping.")
            top = topgrade(grade)
            a = grade.index(top)

            print("Best students:",name[a])
            print("Best mark:",top)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found:",s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does your code not work? How so?

Comment: It works but only prints the highest value of one person, I want it to print everyone with the highest value. For example if I have 5 students 2 of them have a grade of 88 the first person with 88 will be printed and the other person wont be.

Comment: I found an answer to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21894160/7789666). You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to keep the students and marks in 2 separate lists (with the risk that they get out of step) it is better to use a dictionary - where the key is the mark and the value is a list of the student(s) who obtained that mark.

Then it is a simple task of just printing out the highest key, and the associated list of students. I'm using `defaultdict` as an easier option than having to create or append to the list for each value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

def main():
    s = sys.argv[1]
    grades = defaultdict(list)
    try:
        with open(s,'r') as studata:
            for line in studata:
                try:
                    line = line.strip()
                    grades[int(line[0:2])].append(line[3::])

                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid mark",line[0:2],"encountered. Skipping.")

        top_mark = max(grades.keys())
        print("Best students:{}".format(','.join(grades[top_mark])))
        print("Best mark: {}".format(top_mark))

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found:",s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That is a pretty neat way that I didnt think off. I have to print it without the brackets for the student names, how would I go about that as .strip or .replace do not work?

Comment: I've updated the answer to print the students as a comma-separated list, rather than the list itself.