# How to find the indices of the maximum values of the fifth column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have array A as:

```
    A = [[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1008.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1008.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -4.0, -1808.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -3.0, -1648.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, -1488.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0]]
```

I want to find where the maximum values in column 4 (the fifth column) occur and I want to finally get this result,

```
m = [0 , 1]
```

which is where two -1008.0 have happend. I have tried using:

```
m = np.argwhere(A == np.amax(A))
```

But I don't seem to be using it right. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```py
last_col = np.array(A)[:, -1] # take every row in `A`, but only the last column
print(np.argwhere(last_col == np.amax(last_col)).flatten().tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution that you should convert it to numpyArray by using

```py
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[....],[.....]])
m = np.argwhere(A == np.amax(A[:,[4]]))
print(m)
```

it will give you the result that you expected which is

```
array([[0, 4],[1, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to Numpy, you can achieve this with ordinary lists:

```
A = [[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1008.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -1008.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1328.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0, -1168.0]]


# Fetch only the 5th column
A_col_5 = [x[4] for x in A]

# Find indices of the maxima
m = [i for i, x in enumerate(A_col_5) if x == max(A_col_5)]
```

This can likely be condensed into one list comprehension, but I think that having two is better for readability. If the performance is an issue, consider just one or a Numpy solution - they may be faster/leaner on memory.

Here the program first selects only the fifth column and places it into a separate list. Then it finds the indices of all the maxima using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21894160/2763915).

One important thing here is the comparison `x == max(A_col_5)`. Since your values are floating point values you may not want to rely on a direct comparison with `==`. In fact, I would actually use

```
m = [i for i, x in enumerate(A_col_5) if math.isclose(x, max(A_col_5))]
```

from the `math` module (`import math` upfront), or use integer values if possible.